# gnuradio.py - finding or generating in Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am using Windows 10, 64-bit system and would like to write OOT modules.

I cannot find the file gnuradio.py anywhere in C:\Program Files\GNURadio-3.8.  That module seems to be needed everywhere for GNU Radio.  It is an import file for all the projects I have generated with GRC.  gnuradio.py seems to be generated on the fly when GRC starts.

I found several postings here for the Python paths in the GR installation and added those paths, within Python code, to a Visual Studio 2019 solution / project.  I copied code from the GNURadio-3.8 installation’s gnuradio-companion.py in an attempt to generate gnuradio.py within my project.

No success, yet.  The error message I am getting is “cannot import name '*gi' from 'gi' (C:\Program Files\GNURadio-3.8\tools\python3\lib\site-packages\gi_*init**.py)”.

The GR developers say that doing OOT development on a Windows system is difficult.

I suspect that when this error is dealt with there will be others.

Comment: how did you install GNU Radio? Also, there's no such thing as a "gnuradio.py", not quite sure what you're referring to!

Comment: *The GR developers say that doing OOT development on a Windows system is difficult.*, hm, no, we don't – but the way *you're* doing it might be! You seem to have a couple misconceptions about what OOT development is, and what GRC and python. You definitely don't copy some parts of GRC into anything... this all makes no sense.

Comment: I installed GR via a binary at http://www.gcndevelopment.com/gnuradio/index.htm.

Comment: I see the Python code in, e.g., GRC generated .py files which has, e.g., `from gnuradio import qtgui`.  I an new to Python and so far I have only seen the `import` command used with .py files.

Comment: Fair enough on my "difficult" comment.  In trying to follow the details at https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/OutOfTreeModules, In Tutorial 1 I could not get the  code `% gr_modtool newmod howto` to run.  When I try to run it I get the error, "Traceback (most recent call last):   File "gr_modtool.py", line 25, in <module>  from gnuradio.modtool.cli.base import cli  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gnuradio'.

Comment: What path would you suggest?  I clearly do not know how to do this but am willing to learn.  I have had difficulty finding documentation on how to proceed.

Comment: so, you start by learning a bit more about Python; learning Python by learning GNU Radio is going to be ... hard. (and `import`s can be done on modules, not only files.) Then, start with https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/CondaInstall to set up a development environment in your windows machine.

Comment: Marcus, Thank you.  I will heed your advice and do both.